# Parse.com framework (based on Backbone) model.set not working when looping through collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

When looping through results in a collection, setting a model property doesn't seem to stick when I immediately try to check the value with get. What am I missing?

```
collection.each(function(model){


    var objectId = model.id.toString();

    model.set({'objectId':objectId}, {silent:true});                    

    console.log('model.id = ' + model.id + ' and model.get("objectId")' + model.get('objectId'));

    // model.get('objectId') returns 'undefined' but model.id returns proper id



});
```

As stated in code, model.get('objectId') returns 'undefined' but model.id returns the proper id...

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
var TestCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Backbone.Model
});

var collection = new TestCollection;
collection.reset([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]);

collection.each(function(model) {
  var objectId = model.id.toString();
  model.set({'objectId': objectId}, {silent: true});                    
  console.log('model.id %s  and model.get("objectId") %s', model.id, model.get('objectId'));
})
```

Outputs

```
model.id 1  and model.get("objectId") 1 
model.id 2  and model.get("objectId") 2 
model.id 3  and model.get("objectId") 3
```

So I assume that the actual problem is hidden in the rest of your code. Are you overriding the standard Backbone behavior?

Comment: +1. Just made this fiddle, exactly the same, and get the correct output. Must be somewhere else in the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/wH3wq/

Comment: I'm actually using the Parse.com framework but its based off and nearly identical to Backbone. I'm going to dig through the source and see if the set functionality is different that Backbone. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the Parse framework doesn't allow you to set an attribute of "objectId".

Comment: Yes, you can set the id parameter on the Parse.Object to specify which object you're referring to. However you cannot change an objects id to an arbitrary string.